# How to make application NOT redirect me when app is running and push notification comes and I am NOT tapping on it

Tags: notifications, ios9, swift3, ios10

I have an application and PUSHs work fine when the app is on background I tap on push notification and it redirects me - OK.

But here is the situation which i have to fix:

1 step: I open the app,  working with it, it is active

2 step: notification comes but user is not seeing anything AND he gets redirected to another ViewController(according to push notification info) UNEXPECTEDLY.

I need the app NOT to redirect anywhere when it is active unless the push notification is actually tapped.

Comment: Can you show us some code to see what's happening?

Comment: who created the actual code snippet which _redirects_ the user 'unexpectedly'? you could also share that code snippet, but it is more likely that you may need to revise how your custom dispatcher works which parses the notification when it is received.

Comment: i posted solution below thanks. it happened because I never checked the state of an app

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!
in didReceiveRemoteNotification method add if statement:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
   if application.applicationState == .inactive || application.applicationState == .background {
        //here add you actions
   }
}
```